# Restricting file access to certain users

Tags: c#, authentication, iis-7, web-config, authorization

I have a site, into which users log in using forms authentication, in which I want to restrict access to files in a particular folder to certain users.

So, for instance, folder `dir/foo` will be accessible to user1 but not user2 or user3 and folder `dir/bar` will be accessible to user2 but not user1 or user3.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User roles then setup the locations in web.config

```
<location path="foo">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="fooUsers"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

OR
for each folder created add a new web.config to folder root

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="folderUsers"/>
            <deny users="*" />              
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's not as simple as that - the folders are created dynamically and so there is no way of knowing at any point in time how many folders there are.

Comment: Then when you create a folder also create an folder specific web.config to put in that folder

Comment: Are you saying that this new web.config will only need to contain this location tag?

Comment: Problem is that the roles of the users do not have any bearing on whether they can access the files or not.

Comment: then allow users instead of roles

Comment: new users will be created on the site all the time.

Comment: I don't get it.. do you want to restrict access without using users or roles..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11689/discussion-between-sachin-kainth-and-jrb)

Answer (score 0):

check the [<location>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692.aspx) element of web.config