# Restricting file access to certain users to certain folders

Tags: c#, authentication, iis-7, web-config, authorization

I have a site, into which users log in using forms authentication, in which I want to restrict access to files in a particular folder to certain users.

So, for instance, folder `dir/foo` will be accessible to `user1` but not `user2` or `user3` and folder `dir/bar` will be accessible to `user2` but not `user1` or `user3`.

The folders mentioned above are not created at the point at which I deploy the site.  They are created throughout the lifecycle of the website and I can know through code (by the names of the files) who should have access to which files.

My setup is such that I have some users who have roles of `Member`.  A `Member` represents a company.  Each `Member` has users with roles of `Seller`, `Buyer` and `Viewer`.  Now, each user whether he is a `Member`, `Seller`, `Buyer` or `Viewer` should be able to see documents that belong to his company.  So, if `Seller1` has a document `a.txt` then `Seller1` should be able to see it, `Member1` should be able to see it (`Member1` is the company to which `Seller1` belongs), `Buyer1` should be able to see it (belongs to `Member1`), `Viewer1` should be able to see it (belongs to `Member1`), but `Buyer2` should not be able to see it (if he belongs to `Member2`).  Documents are placed in folders that are named after the name of the user to whom the document belongs.  For example, documents belonging to `Seller1` are in a folder called `Seller1`.  Also, there is a user called `Admin` who can see all documents.

How can I do this?

Comment: repost of [Restricting file access to certain users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738673/restricting-file-access-to-certain-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this in your web.config file. It would be better if you organized users into groups, but it's possible to do it on a user by user basis:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <!-- GLOBAL authorization -->
            <allow users="user1" />
            <deny users="user2, user3"/>
            <allow roles="GoodUsers" />
            <deny roles="BadUsers, MouthBreathers"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <!-- local individual folder/file authorization
    <location path="/dir/foo">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="user1" />
                <deny users="user2, user3"/>
                <allow roles="GoodUsers" />
                <deny roles="BadUsers, MouthBreathers"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

**Edit:**
Given your updated description adding the document management aspect and the additional filter of adding a company to the mix there are a few ways you can do it. The primary method I would suggest is to have all documents outside of your root folder so they can't be browsable by any random user. Then build a page-based interface that provides search capacity. Depending on the number of folders/documents this can be done in a number of ways. If the document count is low per folder (less than 1000 per folder, less than 1000 folders) then you could easily have your system access the file system directly to provide read access to these file lists. If you have more than this, I would recommend having an external mechanism to index these files into a database that is easily searchable. Then your interface will be responsible for determine who sees which files.

Finally, to serve the files to the user, you would build a second page whose specific responsibility is to fetch a specific file and serve it out as a binary stream.

Comment: But new users will be created on the site all the time.

Comment: @SachinKainth - which is why I recomend using groups for the users. This way a user simply needs to be added to the group. I'll post an edit showing how it is limited by group (role).

Comment: It's not as simple as that.  It's a long thing to explain but the logic will have to be dealt with in code.

Comment: @SachinKainth - You need to explain it.  What you explain so far is easily done with groups.  You need to either explain the reasons you cannot use groups or explain your question in more detail.

Comment: @SachinKainth: The first page should be fairly easy. During page execution you have the groups, so you just have to provide a manner of filtering/searching based on the folder structure. You would use the `DirectoryInfo` class to perform your structured searches to generate file lists. As for delivering the file, it would be done with `Response.BinaryWrite` -- example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848679/reading-a-binary-file-and-using-response-binarywrite